# Gremlin.Net Casting from Enumerable.SelectIListIterator object to real type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, gremlin, janusgraph

I don't know if my question is about c# and casting or related to Gremlin.net Library return Types. I am using this query to get vertices with their db ids.

```
 g.V().As("vertex").ValueMap<IDictionary<string, object>>()
  .As("properties").Select<object>("vertex", "properties")
  .ToList()
```

properties is a list of attribute of the vertex. when I try to get the value of any property I found that its type is object with the below definition
 *property.Value =
{System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator< Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken, object>}*

I can't find a way to cast it to get the value.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the value from *{System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator< Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken, object>}* object you can use:

`(property.Value as IEnumerable<object>).Cast<object>().ToList()` this will return **List< object>**

Comment: Cast<object>() is un-necessary